# groovy httpbuilder working but grails giving peer not authenticated error

Tags: grails, ssl, groovy

Have a web service I am consuming.

In Groovy:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder( "https://${ip}/convert/" )
http.get( path: 'myTool',
            query: [  name:'myname' ] ) { resp, name ->
    String name = name.toString()
}
```

Which works fine

However, running something similar in grails:

```
class NamingService {

def convertName(String _name) {

    String ip = "server/ip/end/address"
    String convertedName = null
    def http = new HTTPBuilder( "$ip/convert/" )
    try {
        http.get( path: "myTool",
                query: [ name:'myname' ] ) { resp, name ->
            convertedName = name
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println(e.message)
    }
    finally {
        return convertedName
    }
  }
}
```

Grails version is giving: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Why is the grails version giving this but the groovy version not?  The project is mostly stock (haven't added a custom ssl certificate or anything).

Comment: It sounds like Groovy *is not* performing hostname verification.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in the pure Groovy example you are hitting the HTTPS endpoint explicitly:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder( "https://${ip}/convert/" )
```

while in the Grails example you are not specifying HTTPS:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder( "$ip/convert/" )
try {
    http.get( path: "myTool",
            query: [ name:'myname' ] ) { resp, name ->
        convertedName = name
    }...
```

I would try modifying the first line of that Grails excerpt to specify the HTTPS protocol. Without knowing the endpoint I can't verify.